# Cannot override validation error message

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i want to override the default password match error message for primefaces, so here's what i did:

under **src/main/resources**: i created a properties file called **messages.properties**
and added the following keys/values to it:

```
primefaces.password.INVALID_MATCH = Passwords doesn't match
primefaces.password.INVALID_MATCH_detail = Passwords doesn't match
```

and in the **faces-config**, i added the following:

```
 <application>

   <locale-config>
  <default-locale>en</default-locale>
   </locale-config>
   <message-bundle>
        resources.messages
   </message-bundle>
```

but it still prints the default message, please advise.

Comment: `src/main/resources` suggests that you're using Maven. I don't do Maven, but does this really ultimately end up in the `resources` package in the classpath root (the `/WEB-INF/classes` folder of the WAR), as expected by your `<message-bundle>` configuration? If it didn't, then you've there the cause of the problem: it simply can't find the message bundle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that primefaces got

*Messages.properties* and *Messages_en.properties*

Try to rename it into `Messages.properties` with a capital `M` (*best practice*) and try adding `Messages_en.properties` too (cause the one that inside the primefaces jar might override your new Messages.properties)

```
<message-bundle>
    resources.Messages
</message-bundle>
```

(if `main` being part of the package name try adding it before the `resources`)

Comment: Whilst it's indeed a "best practice" problem, uppercase/lowercase should however *not* matter as to the functionality.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just adding validatorMessage ?

```
<p:password id="password1" required="true"   requiredMessage="Password required"
 match="password2" validatorMessage="Passwords doesnt match">
</p:password>
```